# How to config OpenID in angular-oauth2-oidc so that some address doesn't need to authenticate

Tags: angular, typescript, openid, angular-oauth2-oidc

I use the [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) project for OpenId in an Angular project.
For some reason, I want to disable the authentication for some routes.
I initialize the code flow in the main component and bootstrap it to the bootstrap section of the main module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to exclude some routes, it's better to change the bootstrapped component
and initialize
the code flow in the authorized component.
create a main component and two other components for authorized and non-authorized URLs then
bootstrap the main component in the main module and based on user routing load one of the created components.

Comment: thank you
My problem was solved by this method you said